# How to change fixed div position to absolute when it overlaps parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Having this div's:

```
<div id="siteContainer">
    <div id="Shadow">
        <div id="Border">
            <div id="Display">
                <div id="NBar"></div>
                <!-- End NBar -->
                <div id="Screen"></div>
                <!-- End Tablet Screen -->
                <div id="MenuBar"></div>
                <!-- End Menu Bar -->
            </div>
            <!-- End Display -->
        </div>
        <!-- End Border -->
    </div>
    <!-- End Shadow -->
</div>
```

#MenuBar is set with position fixed on the bottom of the screen (bottom: 0px) and what I want is to set position absolute when it reaches the bottom of div #Display so it doesn't go further downward.

Comment: Can you show us an example of the code you currently have?

Comment: This is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/f7Wpn/

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish in the fiddle? your question doesn't seem to match the fiddle.  give us some more info.

Comment: the problem with the fiddle is that it declares doctype if you put the code in there into a blank html page ( with no doctype ) you will see it ok.

Comment: What i want to do is have div #MenuBar with position fixed at the bottom until it "hits" the bottom of #Display ( in fiddle ) and when it is there change position to absolute so it doesn't go further downward

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work as I wanted with this code:

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $("#MenuBar").height().valueOf() * 2) {
        $("#MenuBar").addClass("fixedMenu");
    } else {
        $("#MenuBar").removeClass("fixedMenu");
    }
});
```

I want to know if there might be a better way to do it.